# when moving views to a new subdirectory, what changes must be made and why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Im building an social networking app with the devise gem and have some views in the directory app/views/users for displaying a list of the current users

```
_user.html.erb, index.html.erb, show.html.erb
```

the routes for users is

```
users GET /users(.:format) users#index
```

Because I am using custom devise controllers I needed to move my devise views from the devise directory to the users directory, and to keep things organized I moved the users views to a new subdirectory users/views. This caused them to stop working until i added

```
render 'users/view/index'
```

to the users_controller.rb:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def index
    @users = User.all
    render 'users/view/index'
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    unless @user == current_user
      redirect_to :back, :alert => "Access denied."
    end
  end
end
```

but only after I removed this code from the index.html.erb file in users/view

```
    <% @users.each do |user| %>
        <tr>
            <%= render user %>
        </tr>
    <% end %>
```

which was producing the error:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate in Users#index
```

I was just hoping someone could explain to me not only what I need to do to fix this issue, but also WHY. Also, if there is a better way for me to be doing this please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Rails does some magic in this line:

```
<%= render user %>
```

It identifies the class of an instance and loads a corresponding partial to render the view. If you place view files at un-common places this logic does not work anymore and you have to write more code yourself.

Replace the line with something like this:

```
<%= render partial: 'users/view/user',  locals: { user: user } %>
```

Comment: Awesome thanks! That worked however now I'm getting errors if I click on a user to view it from there: Missing template users/show, application/show with {:locale=>[:en]...

Comment: Is there a way that I could fix all of this so that It doesn't need the partials to work, but works "as it should", if that makes sense...?

Comment: My advise: Do not try to fight against Rails conventions. You cannot expect that all the Rails magic still works if you do not follow the conventions. You want to store the file in a non default folder, fine, but than you are on your own...

Comment: Yea thats exactly what I do not want to do, I was just wondering if there was a way to do what I'm trying to do correctly with these views in the folder I want them in. The reason being I have all the devise folders in the users view folder now and Id like to have the specific user views in their own as well, especially when i begin to add more